# Как нанести кадастровую карту на Яндекс карты?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Не знаю, как получить результат, похожий на этот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*<sup>Источник — https://poselok-shato.ru/plan</sup>*

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: К сожалению, нет понимания, как вообще приступить к этой задаче.

Answer (score 1):

Варианта решения два:

1. Получить нужные вам данные с кадастровой разметкой каким-либо образом в формате geoJSON или KML, а затем импортировать в [JS API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson) или карту [Конструктора](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/).
2. Открыть [Конструктор](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/) и нарисовать вашу карту вручную.

Первый вариант требует получения исходных данных в определённом формате. Если у вас есть доступ к таким данным или вы знаете где и как его купить - это лучшее решение.

Второй потребует много ручной работы, которая может оказаться не столь точной, как вы хотели бы получить. Но зато этот способ доступен каждому и вполне пригоден для случаев, когда нужно просто создать карту дачных участков для вставки на сайт, например.